# PostgreSQL: issues with join + outer-join + sub-select to compare values.

Tags: sql, postgresql, having

I am using postresql but i am realy bad at construting sql queries. 
I have this query and it works:

```
SELECT handhistories FROM handhistories 
JOIN pokerhands using (pokerhand_id)  
JOIN gametypes using (gametype_id)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN playerhandscashkeycolumns using (pokerhand_id)
     WHERE pokerhands.site_id=0  
     AND pokerhands.numberofplayers>=5 and  pokerhands.numberofplayers<=7
     AND (bigblind = 2 OR bigblind = 4 )
     AND player_id in 
        (SELECT player_id FROM playerhandscashkeycolumns GROUP BY player_id
         HAVING AVG(case didvpip when true then 100::real else 0 end) <= 20 )
```

but i also want to limit the last "having" from the bottom so it will be something like this, but ofcourse it does not work.

```
SELECT handhistories FROM handhistories 
JOIN pokerhands using (pokerhand_id)  
JOIN gametypes using (gametype_id)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN playerhandscashkeycolumns using (pokerhand_id)
       WHERE pokerhands.site_id=0  
       AND pokerhands.numberofplayers>=5 and  pokerhands.numberofplayers<=7
       AND (bigblind = 2 OR bigblind = 4 )
       AND player_id in 
        (SELECT player_id FROM playerhandscashkeycolumns GROUP BY player_id
         HAVING AVG(case didvpip when true then 100::real else 0 end) <= 20
         AND  HAVING AVG(case didvpip when true then 100::real else 0 end) > 10 )
```

how to "save" value that is after the having so i can compare it also from the bottom?
Thank you all.

Comment: The didvpip is a boolean, and you want to select a percentage(range)  ? ALSO: please add the tabledefinitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly what **@wildplasser** already pointed out
.. minus the mistake with `BETWEEN`
.. plus `JOIN` instead of `IN` construct, which is usually faster in PostgreSQL.
.. easier to read

```
SELECT handhistories
FROM   handhistories
JOIN   pokerhands USING (pokerhand_id)  
JOIN   gametypes USING (gametype_id)
RIGHT  JOIN playerhandscashkeycolumns USING (pokerhand_id)
JOIN   (
    SELECT player_id
    FROM   playerhandscashkeycolumns
    GROUP  BY player_id
    HAVING avg(CASE WHEN didvpip THEN 100::real ELSE 0 END) >  10
    AND    avg(CASE WHEN didvpip THEN 100::real ELSE 0 END) <= 20
    ) p USING (player_id)
WHERE  pokerhands.site_id = 0  
AND    pokerhands.numberofplayers BETWEEN 5 AND 7
AND    bigblind IN (2,4);
```

You table-qualify some columns, like `pokerhands.site_id`, but not others, like  `handhistories`, you might want to clean that up.

Answer (score 1):

Would BETWEEN work for you ?

```
HAVING AVG(case didvpip when true then 100::real else 0 end) BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

(BTW: ugly SQL syntax, reusing the AND keyword)

UPDATE: can also be used to simplify the rest of your query:

```
AND pokerhands.numberofplayers BETWEEN 5 AND 7
AND bigblind IN ( 2, 4 )
```

Comment: `x BETWEEN 10 AND 20` translates to `x >= 10 AND x <= 20` and **not** `x > 10 AND x <= 20` as requested.

Comment: The devil is in the detail. The most practical way to implement a range still is (x >= a && a < b), IMHO. But that would have confused the COBOL-brains...